# После обновления Debian 12 (Gnome) пропал Nautilus

Tags: linux, debian, apt

Прилетело обновление на Debian 12 (Gnome). Ушел на перезагрузку, обновился, а в итоге пропал Nautilus.

Попробовал установить его заново:

```
sudo apt install nautilus
```

На что apt мне выдал следующее:

```
Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 nautilus : Зависит: libgnome-desktop-3-19 (>= 3.17.92) но он не может быть установлен
            Зависит: libtracker-sparql-2.0-0 (>= 1.12.0) но он не может быть установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты.
```

Пробовал отдельно устанавливать вышеуказанные зависимости, но таких пакетов нет в репозиториях:

```
Для пакета «libgnome-desktop-3-19» не найден кандидат на установку
```

Собственно вопрос: как диагностировать и лечить? Гуглёж ничего толком не дал - конкретно про наутилус кейсов не нашёл. Сам в линуксе не очень много понимаю.

Прикладываю sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 12.2.0 _Bookworm_ - Official amd64 NETINST with firmware 20231007-10:28]/ bookworm main non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware non-free contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main non-free-firmware
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main non-free-firmware

# bookworm-updates, to get updates before a point release is made;
# see https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_updates_and_backports
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware non-free contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware non-free contrib

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Вывод apt show nautilus:

```
Package: nautilus
Version: 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.2
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers <pkg-gnome-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 2 064 kB
Depends: bubblewrap, desktop-file-utils (>= 0.7), gsettings-desktop-schemas (>= 3.8.0), gvfs (>= 1.3.2), libglib2.0-data, libnautilus-extension1a (= 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.2), nautilus-data (= 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.2), shared-mime-info (>= 0.50), tracker, tracker-miner-fs, tracker-extract, libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.32.0), libc6 (>= 2.29), libcairo-gobject2 (>= 1.10.0), libcairo2 (>= 1.14.0), libdbusmenu-glib4 (>= 0.4.2), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.25.2), libgexiv2-2 (>= 0.10.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.58.1), libgnome-autoar-0-0 (>= 0.2.1), libgnome-desktop-3-19 (>= 3.17.92), libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (>= 1.0.0), libgstreamer1.0-0 (>= 1.0.0), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.22.27), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.44.6), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.42), libselinux1 (>= 2.0), libtracker-sparql-2.0-0 (>= 1.12.0), libunity9 (>= 3.4.6)
Recommends: gvfs-backends, librsvg2-common
Suggests: eog, evince | pdf-viewer, gnome-sushi, nautilus-extension-brasero, nautilus-sendto, totem | mp3-decoder, xdg-user-dirs
Breaks: totem (<< 3.31.91-1)
Replaces: totem (<< 3.31.91-1)
Homepage: https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Nautilus
Task: ubuntu-desktop-minimal, ubuntu-desktop
Download-Size: 600 kB
APT-Sources: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
Description: файловый менеджер и графическая оболочка для GNOME
 Nautilus — официальный файловый менеджер для графической среды рабочего
 стола GNOME. Он позволяет манипулировать каталогами, просматривать миниатюры
 содержимого файлов и запускать приложения, ассоциированные с ними. Также он
 отвечает за работу со значками на рабочем столе GNOME, с его помощью
 доступны локальные и удалённые файловые системы.
 .
 В отдельных пакетах доступно несколько тем оформления значков и компонентов
 для просмотра различных типов файлов.

N: Есть 1 дополнительная запись. Используйте «-a» для просмотра.
```

Comment: Что печатает `apt show nautilus`?

Comment: У меня другая версия: `libgnome-desktop-3-20`

Comment: Дополнил вопрос выводом apt show nautilus

Comment: У меня кстати установлен тоже libgnome-desktop-3-20.

Comment: У вас Наутилус из Убунты. Кажется, вы когда-то накатывали ubuntu-desktop. Пакеты есть, а ссылок на репозитории нет. Попробуйте удалить Наутилус и поставить заново. Должна получится версия `43.2-1` а не `1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.2`

Comment: Проблема в том, что при попытке удалить пакет, система пишет, что пакета нет. Удалял через `apt remove/autoremove/purge`

Comment: `$ whereis nautilus`
`nautilus: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nautilus`

Comment: Я не спец, но попробуйте добавить ссылки на репозитории из которых ставился десктоп. Затем удалите наутилус. Если вы что-то ставите из убунты а затем удаляете репозитории убунты - получается плохо. Лучше вычищать пакеты из этих репозиториев до удаления ссылок. Но ещё раз - я не спец.

Comment: Вроде бы из убунты ничего не ставил, но не уверен. До этого стоял дистро PopOS, он как раз на пакетной основе убунту жил. Но что-то сомневаюсь, что после переустановки системы могло что-то сохраниться от него.

Comment: В любом случае попробовал добавить убунтовский репо и удалить наутилус - не помогло

Comment: Как именно не помогло? Он удалился? Потом вы отключили репо и поставили его? Поставился гномовский? Между переключениями репо вы апдейт кеша делали?

Comment: Добавил репозиторий, попробовал удалить наутилус - не вышло, пакета по прежнему нет в системе.

Comment: Между переключениями репо вы апдейт кеша делали (`apt update`) ?

Comment: Да, делал апдейт